# Is there a way to change the way flip3d displays?

Tags: windows-7, aero, expose

**I'm curious if there is a way to get Win7's native flip 3d to display more like Expose or a ring switcher?**

It would improve my workflow drastically if I could more clearly see all my windows at once.

**UPDATE:** It may be part of the SetPoint software... I'm not sure. But while configuring my mouse I noticed a function called "Application Switcher". It works pretty good.

Comment: There's something like that in the MS IntelliPoint sofware, but not as slick looking as Exposé.

Comment: If the SetPoint software answered your question, then why don't you post that as an answer and accept it in a few days if you don't get anything better by then? That way, people will know you already solved your problem, and the question won't remain unanswered forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SetPoint software from Logitech seems to be adequate. It's functionally similar to expose but it's a bit sluggish. Still, the best solution I've seen so far.

Answer (score 1):

Not natively, but you can install [Switcher](http://insentient.net/) (free) or [TopDesk](http://www.otakusoftware.com/topdesk/) (commercial) to emulate the Exposé effect. A [quick search](http://www.google.com/search?q=windows+expose) reveals several other programs that do this, if neither of the ones I mentioned suit your fancy.

Note that I haven't found a single Windows program to implement Exposé as flawlessly as Macs do, but I'm sure they are good enough for your purposes.

Comment: Switcher was ok... but it did earn me a couple BSODs last time I tried it.